# Collision of keybindings

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

I'm using currently Sublime Text 3. I've noticed that when I try to use some default keyboard shortcut, such as `CTRL+L` for example, nothings happen. I assume that some of systems keyboard shortcut overrides it.

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to check for the current window shortcuts first, rather ten system ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are under the wrong assumption. CTRL+L isn't bound to any system function by default. You can test this with Chrome, Nautilus and other applications that use the same keybinding.

My guess is that there is a key conflict in Sublime itself. I would recommend installing the [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) plugin to find it.

Comment: @AdrianBaran No problem. I hope you find the "culprit" ;)